# Android - Button covering TextView in RelativeLayout only in version 5.0+

Tags: java, android

**The target I need to achieve:** 2 lines of text and 1 straight line in between should always be on top of `Button`. So in such a case, setting text in `Button`'s attribute is not applicable according to my knowledge. Therefore I use `TextView` and `View` aligning on top of `Button` to achieve it.

**Problem:** A strange UI appearance I have come across of Android 5.0+ is that when the `Button` is enabled, it covers `TextView` and `View` even it comes before `TextView` in `RelativeLayout` xml file. (according to my knowledge, this means that `TextView` should on top of `Button`) The following is my xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/rl_daily_check_in_button_container"
    android:layout_width="140dp"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textview_check_in_days_in_row">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_daily_check_in"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:background="@drawable/daily_checkin_button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_check_in"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view_line"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:text="@string/title_not_yet_daily_check_in"
        android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="36sp" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_line"
        android:layout_width="94dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textview_check_in_points"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:background="@color/text_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_check_in_points"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/points_can_get_daily_check_in_placeholder"
        android:textColor="@color/text_gray"
        android:textSize="14sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

But when the app is in Android 5.0-, say 4.4.2, the UI is exactly what I expect. I have tried to set `android:elevation="xxdp"` attribute, it success until I set the background of `Button` programatically. Can anyone explain the reason and how the Andoird 5.0+ render its UI? Many Thanks!

`Button` on Andoird 5.0+:

[image]

`Button` on Android 5.0-:

[image]

Comment: Solved by replacing `Button` with `ImageView`...Don't know why this way works. Anyone tells more about the story?

Answer (score 5):

From Android Lollipop (5.0), the `Button` has a default [StateListAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/StateListAnimator.html). It has set the default `android:elevation` and `android:translationZ` attributes to the `Button`. Since the `Button` has default elevation set to it, it appears above the other Views that doesn't have elevation set (Views that has elevation less than the Button, to be precise). i.e. The Views that has higher elevation set to it will appear above the Views that has lower elevation set.

So that's why, when you changed the `Button` to `ImageView`, the problem is solved, because `ImageView` has no default `elevation` set.

Comment: I experienced this but in reverse. I did not notice my main View overlapped my AppBar because on 5.0+ the AppBar was elevated. When I tested on pre5.0 the AppBar couldn't be seen. My solution was simply a top margin for the main View.

Comment: You could have put the App bar and the main view in a vertical LinearLayout.

Comment: @Dinesh Bob, thanks for answer. How you have got this info? From sources or Android provide documentations/explanations about this?

Comment: I have read somewhere about this way earlier, during the Lollipop release. Button has default elevation set. And from Lollipop, the Views with higher elevation will be drawn above other Views. Actually, i have faced some issue like this in our app.